# "Почтили памятью несбывшееся" - как переделать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> ...Он резко и по-стариковски пронзительно вскрикнул: "Я никогда не
>   бывал в Риме!" Это прозвучало как горькое признание и ощущалось как-то
>   невыносимо несправедливо. Конечно, именно ему и необходим был весь
>   этот Рим... Мы помолчали. Словно почтили памятью несбывшееся.

***Словно почтили память о несбывшемся***? О_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что здесь правильны следующие варианты:

Мы помолчали. Словно **почтили память о несбывшемся.**

Мы помолчали. Словно **почтили памятью несбывшееся.**

**Пояснение**

1) **Мы помолчали. Словно почтили память о несбывшемся.**

Чтить (почтить) память – это **вспомнить с почтением**. Возможные варианты:

Наш долг – свято чтить память (чью? кого?) погибших.

Наш долг – свято чтить память о погибших. http://vestiruza.ru/article/418/nash-dolg--svyato-chtit-pamyat-o-pogibshih

ПАМЯТЬ,  ж.  2. Воспоминание **о ком-, чём-л**. Быть верным памяти **кого-л., чьей-л**.

Родительный беспредложный относиться **к одушевленным существительным**? А предложный падеж относится **к любым существительным.**

2) **Мы помолчали. Словно почтили (чем?) памятью (что?) несбывшееся.** То есть почтили несбывшееся своим воспоминанием.

Мне этот вариант кажется грамматически верным.

ЧТИТЬ, 2. Высок. Чувствовать и проявлять к кому-, чему-л. глубокое уважение, почтение; почитать. Ч. священную память. Ч. классическую музыку.

Answer (score 1):

***Словно почтили память несбывшегося.*** Почтить память (*чью?*)

Исправить нужно и это: *и ощущалось как-то невыносимо несправедливо*. - Вариант: ***Это прозвучало как горькое признание и ощущалось как что-то невыносимо несправедливое.***

Answer (score 0):

Вот несколько опций:

"Мы помолчали, почтив память о несбывшемся."

"Мы помолчали, словно провожая в последний путь его несостоявшуюся мечту."

"Мы помолчали, разделяя его тоску о несбывшемся."

/Последний вариант кажется мне менее удачным, чем первые два./

Comment: Мишель, ты предлагаешь совсем иную стилистику! Нельзя писать за автора! И - ***точка ставится ВСЕГДА после закрывающей кавычки***!

Comment: А известна ли Вам популярная аббревиатура "КГАМ"?
Так вот, когда КГАМ, не грех автора и подправить и написать за него.

Comment: Кроме ВМПС им. Тургенева, никаких аббревиатур по нашей тематике не знаю, а автора правят, не когда у него круглый овальный стол, а когда энтомолог вместо этимолога. Да, и кто будет рукопись переписывать? Издательство? А как на это посмотрит автор? Чьи деньги и чьё имя на обложке?

Comment: КГАМ: «Креатиф Гениален / Аффтар Маладец» )))

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova   ах, озорница :)

Comment: Ну да. А как же ж жить? О_о